# Закрытый дубликат не ищется

Tags: предложение, закрытие-вопросов, дубликаты

При закрытии вопроса как дубликата поиск не находит те вопросы, которые уже закрыты. Было бы удобнее, если бы находил, но предлагал выбор между закрытым вопросом и тем, в пользу которого он закрыт.

[image: скриншот]